# Keep inner div from expanding beyond fixed height outer div

Tags: html, css

I need my last div ("content"), whose height can vary, to expand to fill the container div but not expand beyond it. If the content div's contents won't fit, it should simply scroll with `overflow-y: auto`

However, I can't seem to contain the content div. I've tried a host of css without success and would appreciate some help.

**UPDATE**
I see I left out one important piece of info. I do not want to specify a fixed height of the "content" div since the height of the container can vary (it is resizable). I would have to calculate and adjust the height of the content with each `mousemove` (which I am trying to avoid).

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/0y9fdgsu/)

```css
#container {
  max-height: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
#title {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#tabs {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
#content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <div id="tabs">
    Tabs
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit of a more fun way to do it. Removed your need for putting width 100% all over the place as well!

```css
   

#container {
    max-height: 350px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
}

#title {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

#tabs {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
   
#content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <div id="tabs">
    Tabs
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want more info, this is just using the new flexbox layout (which was developed for exactly this situation!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1

Comment: Flexbox had crossed my mind. It looks like the title and tab divs don't need to have flex definitions for this to work. Thank you, this may work.

Comment: Most browsers do a "smart fallback" if the developer didn't define a `flex` sizing attribute. Though most browsers do this, I'm not sure it's part of the spec other than to suffice the "min-content" scenario.

Better safe than sorry, if the parent is `display: flex` I would specify `flex: 0 0 auto` or some variation just to be safe.

Answer (score 4):

**Explanation:**

Added **overflow: hidden;** to **#container** and added 
**overflow-y: auto;** to **#content attribute**

**Scroll-Demo**

```css
 #container {
     max-height: 350px;
     width: 200px;
     border: 2px solid black;
     display: block;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
 #title {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 2px solid red;
 }
 #tabs {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 2px solid green;
 }
 #content {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 2px solid blue;
     overflow-y: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <div id="tabs">
    Tabs
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mseifert: Glad to hear that! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 3):

`height:100%` is preventing that. Specify height, for example, in pixels.

Or use `height: calc(100% - 208px);`, to calculate the dynamic height. Don't forget to change `max-height` to `height`.

```css
#container {
  height: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
#title {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#tabs {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
#content {
  height: calc(100% - 208px);
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <div id="tabs">
    Tabs
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div
```

Comment: The height is variable. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Yes .if height is 100% you cant set the scroll.This is the correct method

Comment: I tried calc(100% - 210px) but it had no effect. This might have been a possible solution,

Comment: I see that you changed  `max-height`  to `height ` and this is why yours works and my jsfiddle didn't. Yes this might work. Thank you.

Comment: I see a slight miscalculation. it should be `calc(100% - 208px)`.

Comment: @mse Sorry, I've changed it indeed and forgot to mention. If my answer satisfies your needs, please don't forget to accept.

Comment: @Mr_Green Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately,  I would have to hard code the amount to subtract from 100% in the css as it can't be done via js. So in the end, it's too inflexible a solution. I went with a flex box which is the better solution for my case. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `display: flex`.

```
 #container {
   max-height: 350px;
   width: 200px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   position: absolute;
   display: flex;              /* Added */
   flex-direction: column;     /* Added */
 }

 #title {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   border: 2px solid red;
 }

 #tabs {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   border: 2px solid green;
 }

 #content {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   border: 2px solid blue;
   overflow-y: auto;
   flex: auto;              /* Added, this container should stretch in the remaining space */
 }
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0y9fdgsu/18/)**

Answer (score 0):

You wanted only the last table to scroll, right?

```css
   #container {
     max-height: 350px;
     width: 200px;
     border: 2px solid black;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     margin-bottom: 15px; /*just to see the bottom*/
   }
   
   #title {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 2px solid red;
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   
   #tabs {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 2px solid green;
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   
   #content {
     max-height: 138px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     width: 100%;
     border: 2px solid blue;
     overflow-y: auto;
   }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <div id="tabs">
    Tabs
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Code**

```
   <div id="container">
  <div id="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <div id="tabs">
    Tabs
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ABC</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
     #container {
     max-height: 350px;
     width: 200px;
     border: 2px solid black;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;

   }

   #title {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 2px solid red;
   }

   #tabs {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 2px solid green;
   }

   #content {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 2px solid blue;
     overflow-y: auto;
   }
```

fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0y9fdgsu/7/)